# How to see image in Preview in ACDSee?

Tags: acdsee

I was able to see image inside preview in ACDSee.

Now I see only histograms:

[image]

How to fix?

ACDSee is Pro 9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to (Tools menu)>option>preview, and then check the boxes: show image and instant show image.